# Muted role only working in channels everyone can see | Bot discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Okay so I have a bot and the muted role works for channels everyone can see, but when a staff member gets muted they cant chat in the general chats but can chat in staff chats, the staff chats are onlyvisible by staff+ here is the code in case something needs be be changed

````
const { red_dark } = require("../../colors.json");
const ms = require("ms");

module.exports = {
      name: "mute",
      description: "Mutes a member in the discord!",
      usage: "!mute <user> <reason>",
      category: "moderation",
      accessableby: "Members",
      aliases: ["m", "nospeak"],
  run: async (bot, message, args) => {
// check if the command caller has permission to use the command

if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR") || !message.guild.owner) return message.channel.send(":x: **You do not have the permission to use this command!**");

if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(":x: **I do not have the permission to add roles!**")

//define the reason and mutee

let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));

if(!tomute) return message.reply("Couldn't find user.");


let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "Muted");
//start of create role
if(!muterole){
  try{
    muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
      name: "Muted",
      color: "#ff0000",
      permissions:[]
    })
    message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
      await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
        ADD_REACTIONS: false,
        CONNECT: false
      });
    });
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e.stack);
  }
}
//end of create role
let mutetime = args[1];
if(!mutetime) return message.reply(":X: You didn't specify a time!");

await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));
message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutetime))}`);
         tomute.send(`Hello, you have been muted in ${message.guild.name} for: **${mutetime}**`).catch(err => console.log(err))

setTimeout(function(){
  tomute.removeRole(muterole.id);
  message.channel.send(`<@${tomute.id}> is no longer muted! Welcome Back!!`);
}, ms(mutetime));
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, due to new NodeJS update this line is incorrect:

`` let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "Muted"); ``

Should be changed to something like this:

`let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Muted");`

Other than that, it must be some channel permissions. I recently found out if a user (without the specificed mod/ administrative permissions) has "Send Messages" to Allow on one of their roles, they bypass the mute. To change this, their role with this allowed, you must set it to null (the gray option in the middle) in order to deny them from talking via the mute role. Example:

[image]

If I try to mute anyone with "Beta Testers" role, they can still talk in this certain channel, even if muted people are denied it.

I hope this makes somewhat sense, and I hope I cleared out some confusion, and this helped!
Have a nice day